# Data import from postgres to Neo4j takes a lot of time in Talend

Tags: neo4j, etl, talend

I am new to Talend  and I am trying to design a data flow to transfer my data from postgres to neo4j. I am using "Talend open studio for big data" the open source version 6.2.1.

For now I have an initial design which fetches Users and Items , imports them into neo4j and then creates the "USER-[Has_Rated]->ITEM"relation. The problem is that it  is abnormally slow  to insert User and Item nodes ! like 100 users per second ! and I have like 3 million users. I am using an existing db connections , so the slow performance root cause is coming from somewhere else.I enabled the multi-thread option but that did not changed anything. I thought maybe parallel execution can be a solution bu could not find how to add that to my design. 
Anyone has any idea how I can make this faster ? 
Thanks !
Lina

P.S. I know for sure that the export - import process can work faster cause I have implemented a sample code (using LOAD CSV) which inserts more than a million node in a minute!

Comment: Performance bottlenecks are sometimes difficult to find... parallel execution only helps if you have prepared batches beforehand. Why is the speed so different? What does the other procedure do?

Comment: Are you doing any kind of batching, or limiting of the users you're creating? And do you have constraints in place in neo4j on the relevant properties of your labels?

Comment: tobi6 , the parallel execution is a part of Enterprise edition , is not it? The other procedure is a java code that I have implemented , I am using Periodic commits which are kind of batch insertions . I can  not use batch insertions in talend because in talend the batch insertion for neo4j is only supported for embedded mode , I am using a standalone neo4j server :(

Comment: @InverseFalcon No I am not using any batching in talend , because it is not supported for the standalone neo4j servers. No I do not have any limitations  for users I am creating. I create indexes while creating the user nodes. the talend supports it . For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327968/talend-neo4j-relationship-component-throws-error-when-start-node-doesnt-exist

Comment: @Lina, Parallele execution is available in open studio edition, Try adding more memory to the JVM of the Job.